# Не правильно отображается текст в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Даже не знаю как задать вопрос, открываю проект и вижу это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то с темой. А если строку выделить, ничего не меняется?

Comment: Если выделить строку, исчезает текст

Comment: Какую версию VS вы используете? Пробовали обновить VS, или сменить тему?

Comment: Не знаю в чем проблема была, но все вернулось в нормальное состояние, только у всех элементов координаты уехали на -32768, но это исправимо